# Sending a message after several other messages have completed without utilizing an external store?

Tags: java, jms, java-ee-8

I have an application which should use JMS to queue several long running tasks asynchronously in response to a specific request. Some of these tasks might complete within seconds while others might take a longer time to complete. The original request should already complete after all the tasks have been started (i.e. the message to start the task has been queued) - i.e. I don't want to block the request while the tasks are being executed.

Now, however, I would like to execute another action per request once all of the messages have been processed successfully. For this, I would like to send another message to another queue - but only after all messages have been processed.

So what I am doing is a bit similar to a reply-response pattern, but not exactly: The responses of multiple messages (which were queued in the same transaction) should be aggregated and processed in a single transaction once they are all available. Also, I don't want to "block" the transaction enqueuing the messages by waiting for replies.

My first, naive approach would be the following:

When a requests comes in:

1. Queue n messages for each of the n actions to be performed. Give them all the same correlation id.
2. Store n (i.e. the number of messages sent) in a database along with the correlation id of the messages.
3. Complete the request successfully

Each of the workers would do the following:

1. Receive a message from the queue
2. Do the work that needs to be done to handle the message
3. Decrement the counter stored in the database based on the correlation id.
4. If the counter has reached zero: Send a "COMPLETED" message to the completed-queue

However, I am wondering if there is an alternative solution which doesn't require a database (or any other kind of external store) to keep track whether all messages have already been processed or not.

Does JMS provide some functionality which would help me with this?
Or do I really have to use the database in this case?

Answer (score 1):

If your system is distributed, and I presume it is, it's very hard to solve this problem without some kind of global latch lock like the one you have implemented. The main thing to notice is that "tasks" have to signal within "global storage" that they are over. Your app is essentially creating a new countdown latch lock instance (identified by CorrelationID) each time a new request comes by inserting a row in a db. Your tasks are "signaling" the end of jobs by counting that latch down. The job which ends holding a lock has to clean the row.

Now global storage doesn't have to be a database, but it still has to be some kind of global access state. And you have to keep on counting. And if only thing you have is a JMS you have to create latch and count down by sending messages.

The simplest solution which comes to a mind is by having each job sends a *TASK_ENDED* message to a *JOBS_FINISHED* queue. *TASK_ENDED* message stands for: "task X triggered by request Y with CorrelationID Z has ended" signal. Just as counting down in db. Recipient of this q is a special task whose only job is to trigger *COMPLETED* messages when all messages are received for a request with given correlation id. So this jobs is just reading messages sequentially. And counts each unique correlation id which it encounters. Once it has counted to an expected number it should clear that counter and send *COMPLETED* message.

You can encode number of triggered tasks and any other specifics within JMS header of messages created when processing request. For example:

```
// pretend this request handling triggers 10 tasks
// here we are creating first of ten START TASK messages

TextMessage msg1 = session.createTextMessage("Start a first task");
msg1.setJMSCorrelationID(request.id);
msg1.setIntProperty("TASK_NUM", 1);
msg1.setIntProperty("TOTAL_TASK_COUNT", 10);
```

And than you just pass that info to a *TASK_ENDED* messages all the way to a final job. You have to make sure that all messages sent to an ending job are received to same instance of a job.

You could go from here by expanding idea with publish subscribe messaging, and error handling and temporary queues and stuff like that, but that is becoming very specific of you needs so I'll end here.